# React how to build some scripts to be NOT deferred in built index.html?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I use `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript` and I need some setup during index.html loading.

I develop PWA and store some settings in localStorage, some of which i read and apply inside index.html: i set html lang, title, manifest link query params to generate it on server or service worker when user changes language manually. I see that react compiles all the code in deferred script, but I want some code to be compiled in usual, NOT deferred script. I can place some scripts in public folder, but there is at least 2 serious drawbacks: scripts can't be in typescript and fileshashes not generated automatically so browser doesn't fetch new version of script at all when it was updated (browser uses memeory cache). Is it possible in create-react-app or somewhere else?